# reading contents of txt file on local network using java in android studio for android 1.5.1

Tags: android

In my quest to find some answers, i would like to know if it is possible using android cupcake 1.5.1 to open a txt file which is stored on a local network drive (not an internet) and put the content in a string. The content will only be a name, so single line of text.

Or is this only possible as of Froyo 2.2 ?

I've looked at many many examples, but most are all about txt files on http/ftp servers.

I've started now with Android Studio and followed some youtube tut's to be able now to have 3 text lines which have to be filled with the content from the local stored txt files. and a button to manual refresh it, to see if a name in a txt file has changed. Also i would like to automate this with a while loop every minute or so that it checks to refresh.

Probably i also have to permit network or internet access in the manifest i can do that.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "local stored txt files" while being "a local network driver" and "not an internet" and without working with an "http/ftp server"... Seems contradictory.

Comment: Thanks for your comment shkschneider, well windows sees the network drive like any other drive, just like C: D: E: F: etcetera so i will write (via a little program) on windows a line of text to a txt file, and i want to read it out with the pad (cupcake version) and display the line of text. that's all. But if it is not possible with this cupcake version (i can't upgrade) to then all stops unfortunately. The pad will be connected via wifi of course. Thanks.